# 'NoneType' object is not callable using 'find_all' in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is my code, using find_all, but It works great with .find():

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(URL_DEFINED)
print r.status_code

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print soup.find_all('ul')
```

This is what I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "scraper.py", line 19, in <module>
    print soup.find_all('ul')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: I *think* that your problem is that `find_all` exists in only BS4 (where it standardised naming to more PEP8 like recommendations), looks like you're using version 3, which had the naming convention of `.findAll`... Note that using `soup('ul')` is the equivalent of *find all* in both versions

Comment: I am new to python, how can I install bs4 of BeautifulSoup

Comment: I've made it an answer - might be useful for others in the future. I see you're familiar with pip (from your previous question), so should make sense for you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're using BeautifulSoup version 3, which used a slightly different naming convention, eg: `.findAll`, while BeautifulSoup 4 standardised naming to be more PEP8 like, eg: `.find_all` (but keeps the older naming for backwards compatibility). Note that `soup('ul')` is the equivalent to *find all* on both.

To download and install, use `pip install beautifulsoup4`.

Then change your import to be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Then you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Download BS4 from here. http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/#Download

Install it and import it at the beginning of your code like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(URL_DEFINED)
print r.status_code

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print soup.find_all('ul')
```